# Data-content gets stuck on hover (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Whenever I hover over an element and data-content shows on hover, if I scroll fast or quickly, the content gets stuck on page even if I scroll.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GikYF.png)

Answer (score 0):

try giving position to the element, else show your code for more detail.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).